# Groovy count number of files matches regex in the directory

Tags: groovy

I am using this code to count number of files ends with 's' in a directory.

```
            def count=0
        def p = ~/.*s/
        new File("c:\\shared").eachFileMatch(p) { file->
            println file.getName().split("\\.")[0]
            count++
        }
        print "$count"
```

If there way to avoid the temp variable and use some method in File class itself?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not at a computer, but you could try

```
def count = new File("c:\\shared").listFiles()
                                  .findAll { it.name ==~ /.*s/ }
                                  .size()
```

Comment: Why just not use `new File(/c:\shared/).listFiles().count { it.name ==~ /.*s/ }` ?

Comment: @topr nice alternative :-)

Comment: .count fails when no files ;  cannot invoke count on a null object